# C# inspect and modify Expression<Func<T, bool>>?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

My generic repository method is declared like this:

```cs
public virtual async Task<List<T>> GetMany(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filterExpression)
```

I would like to investigate that `filterExpression` and check if `T` is of a certain type AND if so, check if there's a filter for a property called `ShardKey`. Also, if the type checks out but the filter is not present, I would like to add it.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: [ExpressionVisitor Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expressionvisitor?view=net-7.0) - staring point for analysis and tree transformation.

Comment: LINQPad is an excellent tool for looking at the structure of `Expression` trees to help build code to analyze them. You can use the `Dump` method on an `Expression`. You can test `T` directly in C# using `typeof` e.g. `typeof(T) == typeof(String)`.

Comment: @NetMage yeah, LINQPad is great but I need to investigate at runtime, in a dynamic fashion

Comment: Yes, but with LINQPad you can `Dump()` the `filterExpression` (or a sample one) and see how the tree is contructed. Can you add some sample values for `filterExpression` that you want to be able to handle?

Answer (score 1):

Using an `ExpressionVisitor` you can search the `Expression` tree to determine if a reference to the desired property is made. If you wanted to be more sure, you could test to see if it is in a certain type of logical test as well.

If you don't find the desired reference, you can add a parent test to the `filterExpression`.

Here is an example, assuming `ShardKey` is an `int`:

```
public virtual async Task<List<T>> GetMany<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filterExpression) {
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(CertainType) && !filterExpression.ReferencesMember<CertainType>("ShardKey")) {
        var skTest = Expression.Equal(Expression.PropertyOrField(filterExpression.Parameters[0], "ShardKey"), Expression.Constant(7));
        filterExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T,bool>>(Expression.AndAlso(skTest, filterExpression.Body), filterExpression.Parameters);
    }
```

Here is the `ExpressionVisitor` implementation:

```
public static class ExpressionExt {
    public static bool ReferencesMember<T>(this Expression ex, string memberName) {
        var mi = typeof(T).GetMember(memberName);
        if (mi.Length != 1)
            throw new ArgumentException($"{memberName} ambiguous or not found for {typeof(T).Name}");

        var mf = new MemberFinder(mi[0]);
        mf.Visit(ex);
        return mf.Found;
    }

    class MemberFinder : ExpressionVisitor {
        MemberInfo mi;
        public bool Found = false;

        public MemberFinder(MemberInfo _mi) => mi = _mi;

        [return: NotNullIfNotNull("node")]
        public override Expression Visit(Expression node) {
            if (Found)
                return node;
            else
                return base.Visit(node);
        }

        protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression me) {
            if (me.Member == mi)
                Found = true;

            return me;
        }
    }
}
```